# Is there a way to “reflect” ILGenerator.Emit commands from IL code?

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit

I am trying to dynamically emit some generic method that I’ve prototyped in C#.
Based on IL code presented in ILDASM, is there a way to generate adequate sequence of ILGenerator.Emit() commands that finally would compile into the same IL?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You want to convert the string representation of IL from ILDASM into actual IL?

Comment: Nope – I’d like to get something like:
// Generate IL
ILGenerator ilGenerator = getterMethodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
ilGenerator.DeclareLocal(fieldBuilder.FieldType);
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
ilGenerator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, getterMethodInfo, null);
. . . . 
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

Answer (score 1):

FWIW: I've tended to do this by hand, but I've seen a .NET Reflector plugin which sounds like it'd do what you want: [ReflectionEmitLanguage](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ReflectionEmitLanguage&referringTitle=Home).  I've been curious as to what that'd do, but I haven't actually tried it.

Comment: Well, it does generate Emit code – with some errors though. E.g., it used forbidden name CS$0$0000; gen.Emit(OpCodes.Box,T) instead of gen.Emit(OpCodes.Box,typeof(T)), etc. Yet it DOES cover most of the frustrating nitty-gritty stuff and this way is very helpful. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

There is an Add-In for the popular .NET decompiler "[Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/)":
Look for [ReflectionEmitLanguage on Codeplex](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=reflectionemitlanguage)